# Joining an attribute from a has_many through Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, fastjsonapi

I have the following 2 models:

Parent Model:

```
  class Babysitter < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :babysitters, through: :jobs
```

Babysitter Model:

```
  class Babysitter < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :jobs
  has_many :parents, through: :jobs
```

They have a has_many through relationship from the Job model:

```
Model Job:

    class Job < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :Babysitter, :touch => true
      belongs_to :Parent
    end
```

I now want to call `babysitter.parents` but have each parent also include the attribute salary (an attribute from the `Jobs` table).

Is this possible?

I tried:

```
babysitter.parents.includes(:jobs.salary)
```

Additionally is it possible to include the result in a fastJsonApi?

```
parents_including_salary = babysitter.parents.includes(:jobs.salary)
```

options = {
include: [:babysitter, :'parents_including_salary']}
json = Api::CampaignReportSerializer.new(otherData, options).serialized_json

Comment: check out https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use delegate to call the salary?

```
 belongs_to :Parent
 delegate :salary, to: :parent
```

you can try this

in your API can call parent.salary